# How to Get Child values from "restaurants" in android Firebase ? I am getting null values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to Get Child values from "restaurants" in android Firebase ? I am getting null values

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference().child("restaurants").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<RestaurantDetails> foodItems = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> iterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for(DataSnapshot child : iterable){
                foodItems.add(
                        new RestaurantDetails(
                                child.getKey(),
                                child.child("name").getValue().toString(),
                                selectedCategory,
                                Double.parseDouble(child.child("ratings").getValue().toString()),
                                child.child("imageurl").getValue().toString(),
                                child.child("description").getValue().toString(),
                                Integer.parseInt(child.child("count").getValue().toString())
                        )
                );
                Log.d(child.getKey(),child.getValue().toString());
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(shoplistItemArrayAdapter);
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new object of `RestaurantDetails` class because you are getting it from the database. So to solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference restaurantsRef = rootRef.child("restaurants");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            RestaurantDetails restaurantDetails = ds.getValue(RestaurantDetails.class);
            Log.d("TAG", restaurantDetails.getDescription());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
restaurantsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Biryani,Chinese,North Indian,South India
Indian,Chines,Byran
```

If you want to use the String class instead of RestaurantDetails, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference restaurantsRef = rootRef.child("restaurants");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", description);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
restaurantsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo for reply..i tried to implement in  recyclerView with ItemArray Adapter..still i am getting null value

Comment: Using my code, do you get the desired values in your logcat?

Comment: yes..!! i get the values from logcat but how to add the value to the recylerView ?

Comment: Good to hear that. In this case, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex , i will inform you once i Complete the RecyclerView

Comment: Ok @Kaliraj Keep me poested.

Comment: hi @Alex , i check that code..little confusion in creating the adapter class..any idea ?

Comment: little confusion like what? What is the issue?

Comment: I don't know how to create a adapter class based on fire base values to assign @Alex

Comment: Please follow the exact steps that are explained in that post. You should make your own attempt given the information in that post, and ask another question if something else comes up, so me or other users can help you.

Comment: okay @Alex now recylerview works but it display only data from HotKitchen ? and how to display each shop wise details in recylerview?

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.